# Poisson cdf and solving for $\lambda$

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

The Poisson cdf can be written as $F(k, \lambda) = e^{-\lambda} \sum\limits_{i = 0}^{k}\frac{\lambda^{i}}{i!}$. I was wondering if it was possible to solve this equation for $\lambda$? That is, I know $k$ and the value of $F$, but I want to know what value of $\lambda$ makes the equation equal $F$.

Thanks.

Comment: Shouldn't the lower limit of the sum be $i=0$?  You can solve it numerically, but not (unless k=0) algebraically.

Comment: Do you know of any resource that can give me more information on how to go about solve it numerically?

Comment: Any numerical analysis  book.  I like Numerical Recipes, http://nr.com/, chapter 9.  Obsolete versions are free on-line

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$F(k,\lambda) = Q(k+1,\lambda)$ (see, for example, [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function#Special_values)), where $Q(s,x) = \Gamma(s,x)/\Gamma(s)$ is the [regularized incomplete gamma function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RegularizedGammaFunction.html).  This is a well-known enough special function that some common software packages have an implementation for its inverse in $x$.  For example, Mathematica uses the command `InverseGammaRegularized`.  Wolfram|Alpha uses the same command and is freely available, so that may be preferred.

As an illustration, suppose $F = 0.5$ and $k = 10$.  [Wolfram|Alpha says](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=InverseGammaRegularized%5B11,0.5%5D) that `InverseGammaRegularized[11,0.5] =  10.668522...`,
and we can verify this by calculating $$e^{-10.6685} \sum_{i=0}^{10} \frac{10.6685^i}{i!},$$
which [Wolfram|Alpha says](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=e%5E%28-10.668522%29sum_%7Bi=0%7D%5E%7B10%7D%20%5Cfrac%7B10.668522%5Ei%7D%7Bi!%7D) is $0.5$.

Comment: [Should you need to do things yourself...](http://dx.doi.org/10.1137/0907069) you can also start up with [Wilson-Hilferty](http://www.johndcook.com/wilson_hilferty.html) and polish off with Newton-Raphson.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Excel solver in the analysis toolpak add-in.  Use the evolutionary feature.  Minimize the absolute value of the difference between your desired F and the cell that calculates the CDF of your best guess at lambda.  Give it about 30 seconds to run and you'll have your answer.